# Klist windows server command cache ticket

Tags: windows, server

Can anyone show me an example of a couple of screenshots using the klist command to show at least 3
cached tickets (any types) you have obtained from your own Domain Kerberos server.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing this is an exam or homework question given the odd specificity. Please don't post these here without at least showing you've done some work that isn't just wasting everyone's time.

Klist is pretty trivial to use. By default it takes zero command line parameters and lists all the tickets in the cache. On a domain joined machine it'll usually have a couple in there already. Whenever you connect to a server and do Kerberos it'll cache a ticket. Therefore if you connect to a handful of servers, say, the domain controller itself using things like SMB or LDAP or whatever you'll get tickets in your cache. Go do that.